# jar policy file

Tags: java, jar

I'm packaging my java application into a jar file but it only packages the class files.
When I run the java program from the command line, usually this is what I have to do:

java -Djava.security.policy="..\java.policy" Server

My question is: is there a way to package a jar file and include this policy file? For instance, When the user wants to run the jar file, all he/she needs to do is type:

java -jar Server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can package the policy into the jar file and write some housekeeping code to create a security manager from the given policy file. The classloader does the hard work. [Here](http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-security/606/Policy-file-in-a-Jar) is a sample.

Comment: The link is broken, anyone have what it contained?

Comment: please paste the important lines of solutions, helpful in case a url is  broken