# Trouble writing file from within a java applet

Tags: java, jar, applet

I have created simple Java class to test file writes from applets:
**update appeared**

```
public class localfile extends Applet{
public localfile(){
    try {
        File f = new File("testfile.txt");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f,true));
        out.write("test");
        out.close();
    }
    catch(Exception x)
       System.err.println(x.toString());
   }
}
```

I have created and signed jar:

```
jar cvf localfile.jar localfile.java
jarsigner localfile.jar yourkey
```

html looks like:
    `<applet code="localfile.class" archive="localfile.jar", width=300, height=600`>

The error I get every time I run this applet is:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: trusted loader attempted to load sandboxed resource from file:/home/w/test/
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.check(CPCallbackHandler.java:308)
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ParentCallback.access$1400(CPCallbackHandler.java:121)
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ChildElement.checkResource(CPCallbackHandler.java:473)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.checkResource(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:701)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:206)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:520)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:2940)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1444)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: trusted loader attempted to load sandboxed resource from file:/home/w/test/
```

What is strange: I have created similar applet to read files and it works ok.

Any thoughts?

---

I was running this applet on both browser and applet viewer. What is strange given applet doesn't work on applet viewer and throws exception, but on browser it is fine.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission java.security.policy write)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
at java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:725)
at localfile.<init>(localfile.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:785)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:714)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:368)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

So, beside this strange behaviour I consider my problem solved. Thanks everyone:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some finagling, you can include a policy file in a jar.  Refer to the SO question [jar policy file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507994/jar-policy-file) for more information.

Otherwise, consider making a Java WebStart application, which can read/write files more easily.

Comment: Unfortunately Java WebStart is not an option:/ After adding some import applet compiled, but new error appears (access denied), I'm investigating.

Comment: I have the same issue, but with JNLP / "WebStart", so that's probably not a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Did you provide a policy to allow reading files from the filesystem?

Seems that you only signed the jar but didn't use policytool.

Comment: I have created file localfile.policy with the contents:

grant {
permission java.io.FilePermission "<<ALL FILES>>","write";
};

but how to I apply it to the jar?  
btw. I want to write local files.

Answer (score 1):

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/security/tour1/step2.html

This should help you out with creating the policy file and associating with your code base

Comment: I have created policy file, but to apply this policy I have to edit system file. Is there any other approach? Reading local files is granted by default. I would not like to edit system files on all computers used by users of this applet.

Answer (score 1):

I knew this is quite late. But just to help whoever look-up to this error -

Using Ant, multiple jars can be signed at one shot, for example java-comm.jar etc

```
<target name="applet.sign" description="Sign the applet jar">
<signjar jar="${applet.dir}/*.jar"
         storepass="${applet.key.password}"
         keystore="${applet.keystore}"
         alias="${applet.key.alias}"
         keypass="${applet.key.password}" />
```

This wil sign all the jar in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that directory including the file you are trying to load is within the codebase where class files and application resources are looked up. So, you end up mixing trusted and untrusted resources, which is not secure. If the applet is hosted on an http, or better https, server then the issue doesn't arise for files.

Note you can use the JNLP APIs for applets to "open" or write files through a file dialog.

Your resource handling leaves the file open in the case of exceptions. Resource handling should be written in the style:

```
Resource resource = acquire();
try {
     use(resource);
} finally {
     resource.release();
}
```

In your specific case:

```
final FileOutputStream rawOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
try {
    ...
    out.flush();
} finally {
    rawOut.close();
}
```