# Java applet doesn't save/load internal xml files

Tags: java, xml, applet, load, save

I'm making some sort of calculator where you enter amount of items you want to buy and it returns price of these items. The app is loading prices from XML file stored inside jar file.
There's also a popup window where I can modify these prices and save them to XML file.

I'm using NetBeans IDE 7.3.1. When running this applet from applet viewer everything works perfectly. I can load and save this xml file.

The problem comes where I'm running this applet in browser from other location. XML file loads correctly, but when prices are changed and saved it still loads prices before modification.

I've checked paths to finds if there's any error:

```
"file:\J:\root_path\prices.xml" -> load
"jar:file:/J:/root_path/App.jar!/prices.xml" -> save
```

Note: in root_path (directory where jar file is placed) the file prices.xml doesn't exist, so I'm sure that it loads right XML file from inside of jar file.

Anyone had similiar problem?

Comment: You can't write back into a `Jar` file.  Use a database of some kind

Comment: But can I at least write this file "near" JAR file, in relative path or something? I don't want use database, because I will probably have even more problems with it and I'm already pissed off with this java applet thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of security police which is need to run applet from browser. Refer [below](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dba-140353.html) document and also security policy within this document to solve your problem

Comment: Uhm, link you provided is all about database (SQL for example) connections and I'm just loading XML file using Properties class.

Comment: if you want to read/write file from applet running from browser than you need to signed jar + required some read/write policy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088282/trouble-writing-file-from-within-a-java-applet

Comment: Still doesn't work. I've signed JAR file with keytool and jarsigner and added policy file. I can't modify XML file.